# java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/arch/lifecycle/LiveData$1.class

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, apk

well I can run my app on device in debug mode and there is no problem but if I want to generate signed apk it gives this error

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexWithDexForRelease'.
>
> > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
> >     java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexException:
> >     Multiple dex files define Landroid/arch/lifecycle/LiveData$1;

what is the "LiveData.class" actually I dont understand

this my dependencies:

```
dependencies {

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    //arayüz
    implementation  'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
    implementation  'com.android.support:palette-v7:27.1.0'
    implementation  'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.0'
    implementation  'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.0'
    implementation  'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0'
    implementation  'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
    implementation  'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'

    //firebase
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:3.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.0.0'

    //metariel View Pager
    implementation 'com.github.florent37:materialviewpager:1.2.3'

    //Glide
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.6.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.6.1'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This probably happens because of version mismatch of dependencies. A similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49083666/duplicate-entry-error-on-livedata1-class-in-android-studio-when-try-to-generate/49085220#49085220),
I have checked the dependency tree it had:

```
android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.0.0-beta1
```

and

```
android.arch.lifecycle:livedata-core:1.1.0
```

see the mismatch `1.0.0` & `1.1.0`

In your case try updating:

```
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:3.2.1'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.0.0'
```

to:

```
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:3.2.2'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.2.2'
```

which should hopefully fix the issue.

> what is the "LiveData.class" actually I dont understand

Please read [this.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/LiveData.html)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I checked the dependency tree and I saw that some libraries include the android.arch.lifecyle dependency. In my case one dependency included 1.1.0 of android.arch.lifecycle and some other dependency included version 1.1.1. I solved it by adding the following line in build.gradle app module.

`compile ('android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1')`

Now version 1.1.0 is not included anymore because when it is requested by a library it automatically goes up to version 1.1.1.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this from two days and now I solved it today
these are the steps

First Try this in your app level gradle file

```
 implementation('com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.6.1') {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support'
}`
```

if it does not solve try logging dependencies 
run this command

```
./gradlew -q dependencies app:dependencies --configuration compile
```

in your android studio's Terminal Tab
it will log all the dependency tree of your project

then find which libraries are using duplicating dependencies

for example
 `implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.6.1'`
is using duplicate dependencies
so change

`implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.6.1'`

to

```
implementation('com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.6.1') {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support'
}
```

Thats It..

Comment: No man it didnt works. are there a simple way find to see dependencies tree

Comment: post your dependency tree

Comment: Actualy I dont know how to get dependencies from this commend line. how can I use your code in terminal

Comment: Type "ALT+F12" in android studio then paste 
./gradlew -q dependencies app:dependencies --configuration compile
this command in that terminal

Comment: it gives this error messegas Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.16299.248]
(c) 2017 Microsoft Corporation. 

C:\adt\Kpss>./gradlew -q dependencies app:dependencies --configuration compile
'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.