# Duplicate entry error on livedata$1.class in android studio when try to generate apk

Tags: java, android

I really don't konw what is causing this error and how to resolve it

my all dependency:

```
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore:3.2.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.8.0'
implementation ('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.31.0'){exclude group: 'com.android.support'}
implementation'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.6.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.6.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.0'

compile 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:2.3.0'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'

compile 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.6.0'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
```

everything is good but after updating to 27.1.0

it causes me error while generating an apk

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForRelease'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/arch/lifecycle/LiveData$1.class

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) have a look around, and read through the [HELP center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), then read [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and provide a [MCVE : Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If people around can easily read and understand what you mean, or what the problem is, they'll be more likely willing to help :)

Comment: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForRelease'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/arch/lifecycle/LiveData$1.class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This probably happens because of version mismatch of dependencies. 
I have checked the dependency tree it had:

```
android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.0.0
```

and

```
android.arch.lifecycle:livedata-core:1.1.0
```

see the mismatch `1.0.0` & `1.1.0`

In your case try updating:

```
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore:3.2.1'
```

to:

```
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore:3.2.2'
```

which should hopefully fix the version issue.

and note that `compile` is deprecated use `implementation` instead for all your dependencies.

> Update:

You can always check the dependency tree by the command `gradlew your_app_name:dependencies` in Windows